# При перемножении разделить массивы на два. Так как сейчас все находиться в одном. Не могу понять как это сделать

Tags: python

```
def func (arr_1, arr_2):
    c = []
    c.append([])
    for i in range(len(arr_1)):
        for j in range(len(arr_1[i])):
            c.append(arr_1[i][j] * arr_2[i][j])
    return c



b = [[25, 9, 36, 49, 4],
    [49, 100, 36, 81, 49]]
c = [[6, 8, 2, 5, 8],
    [3, 3, 6, 1, 8]]
print(func(b,c))
```

Comment: Попробуйте так: `res = [[xx*yy for xx,yy in zip(x,y)] for x,y in zip(b,c)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенесите добавления пустого массив в первый цикл и добавляете значения не в список, а в последний элемент списка

```
def func (arr_1, arr_2):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(arr_1)):
        c.append([])
        for j in range(len(arr_1[i])):
            c[-1].append(arr_1[i][j] * arr_2[i][j])
    return c
```